# Is Cloud Print to blame for my inability to print?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, printing

I have just moved to the Chrome beta (first 9.something and currently 10.0.648.127) on my Windows 7 64-bit machine, and two of my web browsers (Firefox Beta and Chrome) can no longer print, and neither can Komodo Edit. The problem seems to have started when I tried to enable Google Cloud Print. Frustratingly, I can still print from IE 9 RC, and also from other machines in the office, which means the problem is entirely on this machine.

When I try to print from Chrome, first time I get the printer dialog, and once I click print, it waits, then pops up "Something went wrong", and each time after, it pops up with "No Printer Found". Under Firefox, I get "An unknown error occurred while printing", as does Komodo.

I have printed from these applications before, and have even printed from Google Cloud Print. Once. But then it stopped. I really don't know where to go next in debugging this thing, and the Google results I see tend to be from 2007. I'm not ready for the paperless office yet, so please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all printer entries (and their associated drivers) and then reinstalling them with the latest drivers available from the manufacturer(s).

Any time I run into Windows-based printers that can print from some programs (Test page, Notepad, etc.) and yet only get weird errors from (multiple) others (ie: Office, Lotus, etc.) this is usually the fix.

Comment: Just tried that, via mmc. I may have neglected to reboot several dozen times in that process, but it now behaves exactly as it did before I tried.

Comment: That did it. It took a little bit of poking to figure out how to tell Windows 7 to delete the drivers, and I also uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome, but that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `Google Chrome 11.0.696.28 Beta`, I had frequent problems printing (I kept getting the message `Not responding` and the printer dialog box would not open).

However, Microsoft Notepad would print documents 100% of the time.  I have all the latest printer drivers and am running Windows 7, 64-bit.  Printing problem disappeared after uninstalling `Google Chrome 11.0.696.28 Beta`.

Comment: please refrain from writing in all caps here...Thanks!